# edit php doesn't work it doesn't update data

Tags: php, sql

MY PHP doesn't update data. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>სატელეფონო ცნობარი</title>
<?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $tarigi=$_POST['addedon'];                 
        $teleponi2=$_POST['tel2'];                                               
        $teleponi3=$_POST['tel3'];
        $departamenti2=$_POST['department2'];
        $departamenti3=$_POST['department3'];
        $web=$_POST ['url'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $comment=$_POST['comment'];
        $query3=mysql_query("update phonebook set addedon='$tarigi', tel2='$teleponi2',tel3='$teleponi3', department2='$departamenti2' , department3='$departamenti3' url='$web', email='$email', address='$address', comment='$comment' where id=$id");

        if($query3) {
                header('location:listcnobari.php');
        }
    }
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from phonebook where id='$id'");    
    $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
?>

<fieldset style="width:325px;">
    <form method="post" action="">
        დამატების თარიღი:<input type="text" name="addedon" value="<?php echo $query2['addedon']; ?>" /><br />
        ტელეფონი2:<input type="text" name="tel2" value="<?php echo $query2['tel2']; ?>" /><br />
        ტელეფონი3:<input type="text" name="tel3" value="<?php echo $query2['tel3']; ?>" /><br>
        დეპარტამენტი2:<input type="text" name="department2" value="<?php echo $query2['department2']; ?>" /><br />
        დეპარტამენტი3:<input type="text" name="department3" value="<?php echo $query2['department3']; ?>" /><br />
        ვებ.გვერდი:<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $query2['url']; ?>" /><br />
        ელ.ფოსტა:<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $query2['email']; ?>" /><br />
        მისამართი:<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $query2['address']; ?>" /><br />
        კომენტარი:<input type="text" name="comment" value="<?php echo $query2['comment']; ?>" /><br />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what error it is showing? Also please stop using deprecated `mysql_*`, use `mysali_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I'd strongly recommend you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). SO isn't a place to get your code debugged, that's part of writing the code, show some effort :)

Comment: @A-2-A I think no error, because OP never checks for errors

Comment: @Jens you are right. I intensionlay asked that.`@jeksona113` Please add some error reporting code in given code. Also you missed `,` in your `UPDATE`query  between `department3='$departamenti3' and  url='$web'`

Comment: You have `if(isset($_GET['id']))`, but your form is `<form method="post" action="">`. Where do you expect to get `$_GET['id']` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
$query3=mysql_query("update phonebook set addedon='$tarigi', tel2='$teleponi2', 
            tel3='$teleponi3', department2='$departamenti2' , department3='$departamenti3', url='$web', email='$email', 
            address='$address', comment='$comment' where id=$id");
```

You missed a comma

```
department3='$departamenti3' url='$web'
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma.

change

```
 department3='$departamenti3' url='$web'
```

to

```
 department3='$departamenti3', url='$web'
```